# linux network card packet timestamping

Tags: ethernet, linux, network-core

Curious to know an application that uses hardware time-stamping presented in network cards. If you know any app uses this please list down here.

I saw people writing application through UDP sockets to use these timestamps. But, is there any application (like databases, web page, anything) that is actually using these timestamps in real time?

Answer (score 2):

Some specialist network cards provide timestamping.  The vendor will supply a driver so that network packet capture applications can access and store these timestamps.  No normal business application looks at them, just as no normal business application considers any IP data or packet metadata.

Comment: I think there may be e.g. stock trading analysis applications that use this info, but I guess then the question is whether you consider those as packet capture or normal business applications.

Comment: Any app that u remember using timestamps in stock trading ?